# Create local folder programmatically in MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, meteor, directory, programmatically-created

Is there a way to create local folder in JavaScript using MeteorJS?

PS: App is hosted on Ubuntu server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [meteorhacks:npm](https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm) library to import the Node.js library fs, then you can do all sorts of file manipulation.  Add fs to your packages.json file, then you can do:

```
var fs = Meteor.npmRequire('fs');
fs.mkdirSync(YOUR_PATH_STRING);
```

There's also an async version, and I've heard mkdirp is also popular as a node package.

Hope that helps!